# ! LaTeX Error: Math alphabet identifier \mathrm is undefined in math version `

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

In the following MWE I get the error that `\mathrm` is undefined.

```
% !TeX encoding=utf8
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]

Latin Modern Math        \mathversion{LM}           $\mathrm{d}$    

\end{document}
```

Why do I get this error and how can I prevent it. I want the d to be formated not italic as in the normal math mode.

Comment: Just change `\mathrm` to `\symup`. (It's what I did to the macro `\mathstring` in my answer to your recent question.) See section 3.1 of the user guide of the `unicode-math` package for mor information.

Comment: move the \setmathfont into the preamble, then unicode-math will setup things correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: In a typical use case that would be the solution, however in my document I want to show different math fonts, so that can not be applied.

Comment: Mathrm is not from the math font anyway, use \symup as suggested by Mico.

Comment: the main point of mathversion is to be able to setup various versions in the preamble and then to switch in the document. So I don't understand why you need to setup the version in the document.

Comment: You are right. I can move the Setup to the preamble.